# SQL Function execution using Spring JDBC

Tags: sql, spring, function, jdbc, procedures

I have an sql function in the database

```
FUNCTION RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs ( p_yyyymm VARCHAR2, p_numec NUMBER )
```

the function returns

```
TYPE RATELIMIT_OWN.LOG_RECORD AS OBJECT
   (EVENTID              VARCHAR2(15),
    MSG                    VARCHAR2(2000),
    CREATE_DATE      DATE);
```

I am new to stored procedures and sql functions. After looking at query in the function, it may return multiple results.

I am using Spring JDBC to execute and fetch the results.

```
 SimpleJdbcCall caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs");
    MyBean resultBean = null;

    MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramMap.addValue("p_yyyymm", inputBean.getMonth(), Types.VARCHAR);
    paramMap.addValue("p_numec", inputBean.getNumec(), Types.INTEGER);

    resultBean = caller.executeFunction(MyBean.class, paramMap);
```

But does this work?
if I get multiple results, how does this work. It should return List right.
I couldn't find any SimpleJdbcCall method to return List of objects and even no method through which I can pass RowMapper to map the returning columns to Bean.

Answer (score 2):

You may use JDBCTemplate's query method which will return a collection as expected. Also lets you specify a row mapper. Check this [tutorial part 1](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/03/08/processing-stored-procedure-result-sets-in-spring/) and [tutorial part 2](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/03/09/spring-jdbctemplate-and-stored-procedures-part-ii/)

Comment: It's for stored procedures right. How can we apply this for SQL Functions